# wget - download one file help.php but with many variants of HTTP GET params

Tags: http, ubuntu, get, wget

How to download file help.php via wget, but save many files with different get params.
For example i have two pages help.php?page=1 and help.php?page=2 and i have to save it as two different files.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
for p in 1 2 3 ; do
   wget -O "page$p.html" "http://localhost/page.php?page=$p"
done
```

Something along these lines, but exact handling depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

from man wget:

```
Download Options

       -O file
       --output-document=file
           The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
           will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as
           file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link
           conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)
```

you should invocate wget like this:

```
wget -O prova_page1.php http://www.yourdomain.com/help.php?page=1
wget -O prova_page2.php http://www.yourdomain.com/help.php?page=2
```